# "Ступеньки" на графике training loss

Tags: машинное-обучение, нейронные-сети

[image: График training loss]

Во время обучения сети возник вопрос, почему может получаться соответствующий график training loss. Подобная картина наблюдается и с accuracy. Для обучения разбиваю тренировочный сет на батчи. Когда брал рандомные элементы из тренировочного датасета для батчей, все шло хорошо. Потом решил попробовать исключить повторения при выборе в батч, и написал другую функцию, где каждую эпоху на вход функции поступала перемешанная последовательность примеров из тренировочной выборки. После каждой эпохи последовательность перемешивалась заново. Проблема в том, что с таким методом сеть сначала обучалась лучше, чем с первым, но затем, начали появлятся эти "ступеньки", и процесс обучения стал даже хуже. Подскажите, пожалуйста, в чем может быть дело

Comment: Для получения внятного ответа следует задать более точный вопрос. Как реализовано обучение? Есть ли уверенность в том, что нет ошибок реализации? Как подготовлены данные? Что это за данные? Если это свой код, то я ставлю на то, что там ошибка в алгоритме обучения - на графике большие участки, где Loss либо растёт, либо не падает. А так быть не должно.

Comment: В алгоритме обучения, ошибок быть не должно, так как при другой функции выбора данных в батч для тренировки (случайным образом) сеть неплохо обучалась, график был адекватным

Comment: Возможно есть проблема в данных, с перекос ом классов, но эту гипотизу пока я не проверил

Answer (score 1):

Судя по картинке "ступеньки" появляются примерно через одинаковые промежутки. Меняется ли у вас learning_rate в процессе обучения (я бы предположил, что уменьшается, каждые 800 эпох, если по оси х - эпоха обучения)

Comment: стоило опубликовать это как комментарий, а не ответ. чтобы вам [стали доступны комментарии](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/help/privileges/comment) к чужим сообщениям, надо набрать пятьдесят баллов репутации — это всего пять голосов «за» любой ваш ответ или вопрос